# Responsive menu item that links to its section not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

Am developing a WOrdPress Site and would to know:
How can I make it work that when I click on a menu item it leads me to that section and the content display perfectly on any screen size?

My menu works fine on big screens.When I click on about,it goes to the about section fine. But on mobile devices,this process is not working properly.
When I load the page,and click on the about menu item,it goes to the about section,but it skips a lot of the content of that section as the picture shows:

[image]
[image]

This is how it should look like when I click on the about menu item:
[image]

So. that happens with other sections as well.

This is what I did in jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".burguer-nav").on("click", function(){
       $("header nav ul").toggleClass("open"); 
    });  
    $("#primary-menu > li:first-child > a").addClass("active-menu");
    $("#primary-menu > li > a, ul#menu-menu-1 > li > a, .allcontacts a").on("click", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var bookMark = $(this).attr("href").substring(1,$(this).attr("href").length);
        bookMarkTag = $("a[name='"+ bookMark +"']");
        var animateSpeed = 1000                                                        ;
        if(bookMark !== undefined) {
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: bookMarkTag.offset().top}, animateSpeed );
        }
    });
```

});

```
var num = 150; //number of pixels before modifying styles
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
        $('nav#site-navigation').addClass('fixed');            
    } else {
        $('nav#site-navigation').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

This is the structure of the html:

```
<a name="home"></a>
<section id="home">
  // content goes here
</section>
<a name="about-us"></a>    
<section class="about container" id="about-us">           
   // content goes here
</section>    
<a name="products-and-services"></a>    
<section class="container  products" id="products-and-services">        
  // content goes here
</section>
```

and so for the other sections.